# Google Sheets Conditional Format for Multiple Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using google sheets. For column E, under the header “Received” I have formatted it so that when you type in "no" the color of that cell turns red. But when you type in “yes" then the color of the cell will change to green.

How do I get column F (column to the right of Column E, under the header “Total”) to automatically display the number "20" AND also the make it’s cell
turn to green whenever the cell next to it, in column E says "yes"? And if I type in “no” in Column E id like the cell next to it in Column F to say “0” and the background color change to red.

Please help!

I asked ChatGPT it said to use the formula =IF(E2=“yes”,”20”, “”) however this didn’t work. It only changed column F background color to green but it didn’t change the cell to say “20”

Comment: If you're using Google Sheets, do NOT tag with Excel. They are totally different, with entirely different functionality. Tag spamming (using inappropriate tags) is frowned upon here, and is a very good way to get your post downvoted and/or closed. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should not be abused.

Comment: Okay sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate things. One is the formula inside the cell that determines the value of 20 or 0

```
=IF(E2="","",IF(E2=“yes”,20,0))
```

Or you can set it as an array formula in F2 to expand to lower rows. Put this in F2:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E="","",IF(E2:E=“yes”,20,0)))
```

---

Other thing is the conditional formatting rules that set the colours. Select F2 column and choose conditional formatting. Look for `custom formula` and you can use:

```
=E2="yes"
=E2="no"
```

For green and red respectively. Try these things and let me know

Comment: I copy and pasted both, I get an #ERROR - Formula Parse Error

Comment: Change commas with semicolons, it's probably because of your locale settings

Answer (score 0):

I was able to to get it right using the formula =IF(E2="yes", "20.00", "0.00").
That did the trick, and to change the colors I did conditional format and set it to Text contains: 20and changed the color to green. I added another rule except this time I put Text contains: 0.00 and changed the color to green.

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it! It's not that frequent to use numbers as text, maybe it has to do with your dataset. In this particular case you're handling two possible scenarios and it will work just fine since you don't need to compare smaller than or greater than values, for example. Good luck!